# str_replace or which other function to detect a word and delete everything after it?

Tags: php

What function should I use to search for a string in a paragraph and then delete everything including and after that string?

So if I had a paragraph
"Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then marry went to Walmart for more lambs."

And I used a function to search "lamb" everything including lamb and stuff after it should be deleted. So the resulting text should be "Marry had a little"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this simple task [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr) would work; starting from PHP 5.3, if you set the last parameter to true.

```
 print strstr($text, "lamb", TRUE);
```

This returns only the part until `lamb`.

The alternative would be fiddling with [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr) or for lazy people ,} a regex.

Comment: Good answer, provided the OP has 5.3 ;)

Comment: for some very odd reason, when I used IMAP and read an email from gmail, I am trying to blank out the sender's signature but this function isnt catching their signature...The sender's email gets screwed up by strstr if they are using exchange server or MS outlook...gmail senders are working..

Comment: sill, this one is much slower than the substr stripos one

Comment: @TadejMagajna: Don't microoptimize solely on presumptions. `strstr` is 2.5µs versus the 4.7µs for the `strpos/substr` pair (two function calls, passing subject string twice). Please consider trying the xdebug profiler.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$str = "Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then marry went to Walmart for more lambs.";
$tstr = preg_replace("/lamb(.*)/", "", $str);
```

Comment: regex is somewhat overkill for a simple string match, I'd say

Comment: The advantage of the regex would be that you can watch out for an actual word boundary `\b`, it works with UTF-8 and you could also strip out the preceding space `\s` character. And lastly it would return the whole string unaltered, should `lamb` not be there at all. (If that was the desired outcome.)

Comment: All true, but it's really best to use the simplest solution that meets the specifications, and as the specifications said nothing about word boundaries the substr approach is more appropriate (as it's less demanding than a regex).

Answer (score 2):

A quick and easy solution would be to split the string based on first occurence, and return the first index of the resulting array:

```
$string = "Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all.";
echo array_shift( explode( "lamb", $string, 2 ) ); // Marry had a little
```

If you're running on a modern version of PHP, [@mario's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8333130/54680) is the most elegant.

Answer (score 2):

Not tested, but should work.

```
$subject = 'Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then marry went to Walmart for more lambs.';
$chopped = substr ($subject, 0, stripos ($subject, 'lamb'));
```

Comment: I haven't benchmarked, but I would suspect that to be the case as it does less data copying than using explode, and it's less demanding than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do what you're after.

```
<?php

$text = "Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then marry went to Walmart for more lambs.";

$word = 'lamb';

// replace a matching regular expression with '' (an empty string)
$newtext = preg_replace("/\b$word\b.*/", '', $text);

echo $newtext, "\n";  // Marry had a little
```

I've updated the previous suggestion (which was just `"/$word.*/"`) so it should match whole words only.

Answer (score 0):

```
$poem = "Mary had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then Mary went to Walmart for more lambs.";
$nice_poem = strstr($poem, 'lamb', true); // As of PHP 5.3.0
echo $nice_poem; // prints name although it will keep the lamb to
```

but this should get you close to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) and [substr](http://php.net/substr).

```
$str = 'Marry had a little lamb and the wolf ate them all. Then marry went to Walmart for more lambs.';
$pos = strpos($str, 'lamb');

if ($pos !== false)
    echo substr($str, 0, $pos);
else
    echo 'No match :(';
```